# OpenGL Profiler for mac with xcode 8

Tags: opengl, xcode8, profiler

I've been previously using OpenGL profiler for mac to debug my graphics work and it was working like a charm with xcode 7.2.

I then upgraded xcode to version 8 when it came out, and the profiler was gone. I redownloaded it, but ever since I have not been able to record any trace or stop at any breakpoint, and therefore cannot inspect any resource anymore either.

There is currently no profiler after the one developed for xcode 7.2.
Is there any way to use the last OpenGL profiler with xcode 8.x?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can find [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/204679) a similar post on the apple developer forum.

A bug repport is currently under revision.

> The only way I found to use OpenGL Profiler on macOS 10.12 is to
>   enable remote profiling from the preferences. (checkbox is disabled
>   while you don't set a password) Once enabled, you can connect to it
>   using another machine (it may be 10.12) and attach profiler to the
>   running application you want to debug.